# Django database problem after trying implenet .env

Tags: sql, django, heroku

I have a deployed app that I want to make the repository public, for this, I'm using a .env to store my data, but I am having an issue when I make a request do the database, like logging.

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "$USER"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "FOO", user "$USER", database "FOO", SSL off
```

I runned: `pip install django-environ`

```
on my setting.py

import environ

env = environ.Env()

environ.Env.read_env()

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env('NAME'),
        'HOST': env('HOST'),
        'POST': 5432,
        'USER': env('USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('PASSWORD'),
    }
}
```

before that env change, I was able to connect on te site.

*DEPLOYED ON HEROKU

*I AM RUNNING THE SERVER WITH `gunicorn mysite.wsgi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Heroku, you don't have to include any `.env` file instead of that you have to use the config-vars and store your secrets there.

Read more about including the config vars - https://lovekesh.tech/how-to-create-update-and-delete-config-vars-in-the-heroku-app/

Comment: Ok, but how I tell to my manage.py to use that config

Comment: In Heroku you just add your secrets in config vars and Heroku will solve it automatically.